# Hilbert series of superpolynomial ring

Tags: sagemath

I am recently trying to compute Hilbert series involving Grassmann variables. This means I have to deal with super-polynomials. Is there a way to compute the corresponding Hilbert series in sage once I specify the ideal?

Thanks!